# return by group in specific row

Tags: php, sql

I have `table` name `sample` i just want `level` `row` return by group.

```
level  |  value
-------------------
  1    |   jhon 
  1    |   ren
  1    |   ronron
  2    |   mark
  2    |   nonoy
  2    |   edong
  3    |   pajardo
  3    |   bughao
  3    |   mariel
  4    |   marker
  4    |   jong
  4    |   jazz
  4    |   jhon
```

I just want to output is like this.

```
level  |  value
-------------------
  1    |   jhon 
       |   ren
       |   ronron
  2    |   mark
       |   nonoy
       |   edong
  3    |   pajardo
       |   bughao
       |   mariel
  4    |   marker
       |   jong
       |   jazz
       |   jhon
```

Comment: Do that in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: Tag your DBMS? is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in MySQL, although I don't really recommend it:

```
select l, value
from (select t.*,
             (case when @l = level then NULL
                   else @l := level
              end) as l
      from table t cross join (@l := NULL) params
      order by level
     ) t;
```

I don't recommend it because a SQL table/result set has well defined rows and columns, and it represents an unordered set.  The format that you want means that the definition of a given row depends on previous rows.  Such manipulations are better done at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the output you want, but you may be able to work with this instead:

```
SELECT level, GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM sample GROUP BY level
```